# AMPscript not being evaluated from top to bottom in Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send

I need to skip sending an email based on the evaluation of a condition that I'm defining in an AMPscript block in my email, and also make a POST request to a an HTTP endpoint.

Here's what I have:

```xml
<script runat=server language=ampscript>

var @response, @result

set @result='fail' /* hardcoded for example purpose */

if @result=='fail' then

   HTTPPost('http://requestb.in/1km46cl1',
          'text/xml',
          Concat('result failed for subscriber ',_subscriberkey),
          @response
          )

   RaiseError("Email skipped", true)

endif 
</script>
```

This works fine; if I generate a Preview for a Subscriber, then if `@result=='fail'` evaluates to true, the POST request is made and I see the `RaiseError` message.

However, when I use this email in a Triggered Send, the email is moved to the Error queue (which I would expect), but the POST request is not made. It's almost as if OMM evaluates the AMPscript for any `RaiseError()` function and aborts sending the email (instead of parsing it from top to bottom). Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd remove the [**RaiseError()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/raiseerror/) function altogether and put the rest of the AMPScript in a separate Content Area that outputs `@result`.

For example:

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>

var @response, @result

set @result = 'fail' /* hardcoded for example purpose */

if @result == 'fail' then
  HTTPPost('http://requestb.in/1km46cl1',
         'text/xml',
         Concat('result failed for subscriber ',_subscriberkey),
         @response
         )
endif 
</script>%%=v(@result)=%%
```

Then in the [**Exclusion Script**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213980&language=en_US) field in your Triggered Send Definition, you can check the value of `@result`:

```
TreatAsContent(ContentAreaByName("my contents\path\to\content-area"))=="fail"
```

When the email is triggered, the Content Area will be evaluated (along with the HTTP POST request). The subscriber email will be skipped since the Exclusion Script evaluates `@result=='fail'` to true.

If you don't see the Exclusion Script input box, SFMC support can enable it for you.

**Reference**

- [**Exclude Subscribers from a Triggered or User-Initiated Send**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213980&language=en_US)